# What are the steps to Integrate the Alloy Editor 3.0 and bootstrap 3.2 in liferay 6.2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, liferay, liferay-6, titanium-alloy, liferay-theme

I want to integrate the latest version of alloy editor 3.0 and bootstrap 3.2 in Liferay 6.2, I know by default liferay supports CK Editor,but instead of it I want to use Alloy Editor 3.0 and instead of old version of bootstrap I want to use latest version of bootstrap. What are the steps I need to follow to achieve this?

Comment: if "the steps" would be so easy as to somebody post them here in an answer, it sure would have been done and downloadable (and there would be a big buzz around it). Quite a lot of Liferay's UI is built around some assumptions of DOM and other components to be there. *Is it possible?* Yes, of course! *Will it be **a lot** of work?* Yes, definitely! Way more work than fits into an answer on stackoverflow. Check https://www.liferay.com/de/web/nathan.cavanaugh/blog/-/blogs/the-nitty-gritty-theme-improvements-and-bootstrap-in-liferay-6-6 as well

Answer (score 2):

AlloyEditor has **nothing** to do with YUI or AlloyUI. In fact, we were thinking to change its name in order to avoid such confusion.
AlloyEditor uses the engine of CKEditor and React for the UI. It does not depend on Bootstrap, it has its own CSS.

So, to replace CKEditor with AlloyEditor in 6.2 shouldn't be hard. It depends how good solution you want to provide. I actually would encourage you to add it as another editor, just like we did for Liferay 7. Look [here](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-48228) for more information.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
I would discourage the use of Alloy Editor 3.0 as Alloy will get stripped out of Liferay in the near future. This is happening because of the end of YUI. 
As for your 2nd question: This will be a tough one. You would have to sweep the whole portal and portlet code of Liferay and change all CSS classes to the bootstrap pendants. This would not only include all JSP files, but also all the taglibs, the RenderFactories (for Assets and so on) and a hell of a lot in other places. The question is more: Will it be something that will add such a significant value, that you will go through all of this? 
So short answer: You could make Liferay 6.2 Bootstrap 3 compatible, but it will be a hell of a ride.

AFAIK, Liferay will be Bootstrap 3 compatible with the next release (7.0), but I don't know when the release will be.

Comment: Actually, AlloyUI's implementation will be changed to be based on jquery as far as I know (if the plans didn't change)

Comment: Jep. This is what I recall as well.